# Program Runs Even Though I Return -1?

Tags: c++

I am running this very simple c++ code:

```
    int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

But when I compile it with g++ and run it (on ubuntu 14.04) it goes through and I get no errors. The book that I am reading, "C++ Primer" says that I should receive an error, so I was wondering if someone could show me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "The book that I am reading, "C++ Primer" says that I should receive an error," Please quote the text where it says that.

Comment: I guess it doesn't explicitly say that, but it says in Exercise 1.2 that I should run it to see how my system treats a fail indicator, so I expected that something would say that I made an error. I guess not.

Comment: The fact is a non-zero return value doesn't mean the program failed. For example, grep returns 1 to indicate that it hasn't found anything, but that's not an error..

Comment: Well C++ Primer calls it a failure indicator, so don't blame me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've written here is perfectly legal C++. The program runs and then signals an exit code of -1. On some operating systems, if a program terminates with a nonzero exit code, the OS will report an error to the user indicating that something weird happened. On Ubuntu, though, programs that terminate with nonzero exit codes don't trigger an explicit error message, so what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Comment: "On some operating systems, if a program terminates with a nonzero exit code, the OS will report an error to the user indicating that something weird happened" - can you name one that does this?

Comment: I was under the impression (which could be wrong) that old DOS systems would output "Abnormal Program Termination" if a process exited with a nonzero exit code - though perhaps I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

Your program runs normally, then returns a status of `-1` to the environment. If you don't look at that status, you're not going to see any indication of an error.

If you're running from the bash shell, you can do something like:

```
if ./my_program ; then
    echo Success
else
    echo Failure
fi
```

or, on one line:

```
if ./my_program ; then echo Success ; else echo Failure ; fi
```

or, if you want to be obscure:

```
./my_program && echo Success || echo Failure
```

More simply:

```
./my_program
echo $?
```

Incidentally, returning a status of `-1` is not a portable way to indicate failure.  I suggest adding `#include <cstdlib>` to the top of your program and using `return EXIT_FAILURE;`. (The value of `EXIT_FAILURE` is typically `1`, but it will be whatever it needs to be to denote failure on the system you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `main` is what's called an *exit code*. If you run your program from a shell (such as `bash` on a Unix system or the CMD on Windows), you can examine the exit code. By convention, nonzero exit codes usually imply that something erroneous happened. For instance, your `g++` compiler outputs a nonzero exit code if there's a compile error and `0` if everything goes correctly.

Since you said you're on Ubuntu, I assume you're using either `bash` or `dash` to run this program. Try running the program and then do `echo $?` after running the program. You should see the exit code your program returned.